# Run Xamarin Essentials Browser using cookies from webview

Tags: xamarin, cookies, xamarin.forms, webview

I've got a Xamarin Forms app running on Android and ios.

The app includes a webview. A user signs up through the webview and the web page loaded within the webview sets neccessary cookies.

When clicking on a link in the webview I want to open up the url in the in-app browser using the Xamarin.Essentials.Browser API.

And I need cookies to be shared between the webview and the in-app browser to maintain the user session.

The webview domain is domain.com/app/ and the in-app Browser url is test.domain.com/

The webview webpage is setting cookies on *.domain.com

If I open the desired page (test.domain.com/) in the webview through an iframe the page loads and the user is logged in.

When I open the page in the in-app Browser, after cookies being set inside webview, the user is not logged in.

Is there something essential about sharing cookies this way that I Am missing?

Comment: Essentials.Browser is *not* an "in-app" browser, it is opening the registered browser on the device and thus it is in its own security sandbox

Comment: Sorry, it was a way of saying "not in an external browser outside of the app" even though it might technically be the same thing.

Comment: If you are open a link via Browser.OpenXXXX than technically is it a separate app in its own sandbox, i.e. On Android, Essentials uses "CustomTabs", typically Chrome, but other browsers support CustomTabs, and cookies are not shared to *your* app. You can use CookieManager on WebViews instances within your app to read/create/clear cookies, but you can not read/write cookies from a CustomTabs as that would be a security violation and there is no API for it.